# Error con foreign key en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola estoy haciendo una base de datos relacional en mySQL la cual tiene 2 tablas las cuales tienen el nombre de: 1ra tabla: main_info, 2da tabla: cuenta_empleados, las cuales estaba uniendo con foreign key pero cuando las uni me salio el siguiente error:

> ERROR 3780 (HY000): Referencing column 'andy_handsome' and referenced column 'andy_handsome' in foreign key constraint 'fk_empleados' are incompatible.

El cual entendi que me quiso decir la columna de referencia 'andy_handsome' y la columna de referencia 'andy_handsome' en la restricción de clave externa 'fk' son incompatibles, aunque apenas estoy aprendiendo como funciona el foreign key revise y creo que todo esta bien y aun no se porque me paso este error si alguien save como arreglarlo lo agradeceria mucho.

no se si se importante o necesario pero aqui el contenido de las tablas:

tabla 1: main_info:

```
 Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          

| andy_handsome            | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL  auto_increment    
| nombre                   | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                
| apellido                 | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                
| ubicacion_local_comercial| varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                
| gmail                    | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |
```

tabla 2: cuenta_empleados:

```
Field            | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra|

 IDempleados     | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
 nombre          | varchar(15)  | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 apellido        | varchar(22)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
 ubicacion_venta | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
 andy_handsome   | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
```

y aqui el codigo que use:

```
alter table cuenta_empleados add constraint fk_empleados foreign key 
(andy_handsome)
references main_info (andy_handsome);
```

Comment: Por favor limita que usas por que veo la etiqueta de Oracle y la de MySQL, ¿cuál es el que estás usando?

Answer (score 0):

El error te especifica que la columna `andy_handsome` no es igual a la columna con la que quieres relacionar y es correcto porque en la tabla main_info le especificas que es de tipo int unsigner

```
tabla main_info:
|    columns    | data_type
| andy_handsome | int unsigned
```

y en la tabla  `cuenta_empleados` la declaras como tipo `int`

```
tabla cuenta_empleados:
|    columns    | data_type
| andy_handsome | int
```

Hay que tomar esto en cuenta ya que no son los mismos tipos de datos, el tipo `int unsigned` especifica que no se tendrá números negativos, por lo que su rango abarca desde  0 hasta 4294967295.

En cambio los tipos `int` si pueden llevar números negativos, por lo que su rango es desde -2147483648 hasta 2147483647.

referencia en la documentación de [mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html)

Comment: Hay que tomar en cuenta también que si en cambio se pone solo el atributo `ZEROFILL` entonces [MySQL agrega automáticamente el atributo `unsigned`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/numeric-type-syntax.html) para columnas **numéricas**

Comment: esa no me la sabia, gracias por el dato @BetaM